# Ajax Control Calender Toolkit Validation

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, calendar, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a form of tour application that has 2 dates, from date and To date. now i'm using the dd/MM/yyyy format for the date entry and i need to Validate To date like To date must me greater than or equal to start date. earlier days should be disable, i want to do that with compare validator..

Currently i'm using textbox with ajax control toolkit calendar.

So please help me if anybody have some hints.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can try as bellow:

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cmpVal1" ControlToCompare="txtStartDate" 
         ControlToValidate="txtEndDate" Type="Date" Operator="GreaterThanEqual"   
         ErrorMessage="*Error message" runat="server"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

but there can be issue with date format, Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735836/asp-net-compare-validator-issue-while-specifying-date-format-in-calender-extende) for more information.