# Validation for End Date should be greater or equal to Start Date in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation

I'm using this code to validate two date but the validation is not working when I enter the same or after the Start Date

```
        <asp:CompareValidator ID="dateCompareValidator" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="EndDate"
        ControlToCompare="StartDate" 
        Operator="GreaterThanEqual" Type="Date"
        ErrorMessage="The second date must be after the first one.<br /><br />">
        </asp:CompareValidator>
```

Do i need to use the hard code ?

Comment: what dates u r entering in ur textbox

Comment: i enter by using date picker

Comment: u have problem that when u enter same date it doesnt give error right....and when u left the start date blank than it doesnt give error thats two codntion only right

Comment: when i left blank for both basic time picker, 
enter the same and after End Date 
its give the same Error Message

Comment: after End Date means....what the date is coming in ur textbox pls let me know

Comment: ops sorry, when i left blank for both basic date picker, enter the same and after Start Date its give the same Error Message.
for example :
Start Date : 16 April 2013
End Date : 17 April 2013
its pop-out the same Error Message

Comment: The Format of Date You Are Entering Is not correct...see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735836/asp-net-compare-validator-issue-while-specifying-date-format-in-calender-extende


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735836/asp-net-compare-validator-issue-while-specifying-date-format-in-calender-extende

Answer (score 0):

Aspx File:

```
   <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            Start Date:
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="RadDtpFromDate" runat="server" Calendar-EnableShadows="true" AutoPostBack="true"
                                Culture="en-IN" DateInput-DateFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy" DateInput-EmptyMessage="DD-MMM-YYYY"
                                ShowPopupOnFocus="true" ToolTip="Input Date" ZIndex="30001" 
                                onselecteddatechanged="RadDtpFromDate_SelectedDateChanged" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvFromDate" Display="None" ControlToValidate="RadDtpFromDate"
                                InitialValue="" ValidationGroup="FinalSave" ErrorMessage="From Date is Mandatory"
                                ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vceFromDate" TargetControlID="rfvFromDate"
                                runat="server">
                            </ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                            <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvFromDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="RadDtpFromDate"
                                Display="None"></asp:CustomValidator>
                            <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vceRadFromDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="cvFromDate">
                            </ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                        </td>
                        <td align="right">
                            End Date:
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" colspan="2">
                            <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="RadDtpToDate" runat="server" Calendar-EnableShadows="true" AutoPostBack="true"
                                Culture="en-IN" DateInput-DateFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy" DateInput-EmptyMessage="DD-MMM-YYYY"
                                ShowPopupOnFocus="true" ToolTip="Input Date" ZIndex="30001" 
                                onselecteddatechanged="RadDtpToDate_SelectedDateChanged" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvToDate" Display="None" ControlToValidate="RadDtpToDate"
                                InitialValue="" ValidationGroup="FinalSave" ErrorMessage=" To Date is Mandatory"
                                ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vceToDate" TargetControlID="rfvToDate"
                                runat="server">
                            </ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                            <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvToDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="RadDtpToDate"
                                Display="None"></asp:CustomValidator>
                            <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vceRadToDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="cvToDate">
                            </ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Cs File :

```
 if (RadDtpFromDate.SelectedDate > RadDtpToDate.SelectedDate)
            {
              dateCompareValidator.IsValid = False;
                return;
            }
```

Now Try this..................

Comment: thank you. but still not working. 
when i left blank for both basic time picker, 
enter the same and after End Date its give the same Error Message